# How to get function name after ' } ' in ftrace/ trace-cmd

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ftrace

I have recently started working with ftrace. I able to get function graph trace using

```
trace-cmd record -p function_graph -F <bash command>
trace-cmd report
```

With the above commands I can see time taken by function to finish before ' } 
 '
But I want to script for listing functions taking more time than 10ms.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Edit  your Q to show a small (and simplified if very complex) set of data for 2-3 functions. Include at least one "record" that should not be processed. Then show your required output from that sample input. You'll learn a lot about printing output if you work thru the  [Awk Tutorial printf section](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-27) . Some of the stuff at the top is very technical, scroll down and look for the examples code, work with that, **then** you can understand how the tables at the top of that link can help you tweak your output. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR
it can be achieved by

```
trace-cmd report -O fgraph:tailprint=yes
```

## explanation

as per help

```
-O plugin option -O [plugin:]var[=val]
```

but when we try but plugin name function_graph what we use for record doesn't work
as well if we dig in ftrace docs
we have option `funcgraph-tail` but even this won't work

finally when you dig in source code of trace-cmd

```
trace-cmd/lib/trace-cmd/trace-ftrace.c
```

has these options.